# MegaRaid StorCLI64 No Controllers Found

Tags: raid, megaraid

My system is connected to multiple PERC H800 controllers. I can start the MegaRaid GUI and I'm able to pull up everything after login. I want to use the CLI to script some events but when I go to run it it is not seeing the controllers:

```
# /usr/local/MegaRAID\ Storage\ Manager/StorCLI/storcli64 show all
Status Code = 0
Status = Success
Description = None

Number of Controllers = 0
Host Name = my-server
Operating System  = Linux4.0.3-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64
```

**Why isn't storcli64 picking up the controllers and how can I fix it?**

Comment: I am having a similar situations. With CentOS 7 controller was shown. After upgrade to CentOS 8, storcli shows no controllers. But lshw shows it, and megaraid_sas is loaded. No idea what might be going on.

Comment: I had a similar issue: `perccli64` did work for me, I think it depends on the hardware raid controller

Answer (score 7):

Got it situated. You need to run as `sudo`

```
$ /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c0 show all
Controller = 0
Status = Failure
Description = Controller 0 not found

$ sudo /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c0 show all
Generating detailed summary of the adapter, it may take a while to complete.

Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = None
```

Comment: If storcli fails due to lack of root/elevated permissions, it returns with Status = Failure (as in your example). Ken's example output shows a status of success, so he's likely running this as root.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. sudo is required for MegaCli as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old post, but it's still happening...

In my case the specifics are:
Fedora-38 Workstation (32 cores, 64 threads, 128GB RAM) w/mods to make it more Server-like always available.  LSI SAS MegaRAID 9750-8i PCI controller.  Four identical 8TB SAS drives intended for RAID-10, but that's irrelevant when you can't even find the controller.

According to StorCLI refman, it supports:
 The 926x product line.
 The 928x product line.
 The 924x product line.
 LSI® MegaRAID SAS iMR
 LSI MegaRAID SAS 9280-8e
 LSI MegaRAID SAS 9260CV-8i
 LSI MegaRAID SAS 9266CV-8i
 LSI MegaRAID SAS 9285-8e

Anyone know of an equivalent tool that will work on 3ware 9750 SAS2/SATA-II controllers?

Comment: Hi, this site does not run like a forum, only answers are expected in the answer section.  You are welcome to ask your own question.